# Adobe AIR: Maximum Stage Size for fullscreen App

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, adobe

For a Kiosk application that is going to run on a high resolution display (4k+ in horizontal resolution) we are considering Adobe AIR.

I could not find any information about whether or not AIR can render in this resolution or whether there is a maximum for the Stage size.

The application is supposed to run on OSX in fullscreen on a second monitor.

Is there any information available on the maximum screensize supported or does anyone have experience working with high resultions in AIR / Flash?

Unfortunately we can't test it as we do not have access to such hardware at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

From an [Adobe forum post](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1004158?tstart=0):

> Flash Player 10 has a bitmap limit of 16,777,215 pixels, with the
>   largest square being 4095 x 4095.
>
> ...
>
> Interestingly, if I use a 2400 x 600 video and double it's scale at
>   runtime in AIR, it runs well - so AIR is capbable of updating the
>   screen area.

A [second post](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1012295?tstart=0) says that in Flash CS6

> you can assign the stage to be as large as 8192x8192.

See also [Flash has a limit on image resolution it can handle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883466/flash-has-a-limit-on-image-resolution-it-can-handle)

Answer (score 0):

I have two DELL's - 2560x1440 and 3840 x 2160 (4k) monitors. Don't have any issues with this using Adobe AIR. Use latest AIR 15.0.0.302 from the Labs.